# PHP JSON-RPC - invalid method

Tags: php, json, curl

Doing POST of JSON data using PHP curl. However, every time data is submitted, error message is displayed:

```
{ "result" : null, "error":"Invalid method", "id": default, "jsonrpc": "2.0"" }
```

Of course, my first step was to submit data via browser using Live HTTP Headers plugin, so I can see how raw data looks like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"get","id":1,"params":["2145359"]}
```

So I use this code to format my data:

```
$post_info=json_encode(array("jsonrpc"=>"2.0","method"=>"get","id"=>1,"params"=>array("2145359")), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

When I echo my PHP data, it looks identical:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"get","id":1,"params":["2145359"]}
```

Then I use this curl function to post data:

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, some_post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_info);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

...and "invalid method" error comes. Any suggestions?

Comment: What, specifically, is the invalid method in the error?

Comment: I have no idea, this is the complete messages that comes from remote server

Comment: Magnus, thanks for your suggestion, it's good one. However, data is actually posted (browser posts data, and it works fine), not very sure why "get" is used inside post parameters.

Comment: Just tried not encoding and sending as array. A different error came - "error":"undefined method `values' for "Array":String"

Comment: Ah. Of course. Sorry, bad suggestion. Try using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead of json_encode. I forgot that CURL_OPTFIELDS needs a string, not an array.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I can write it as an answer so you can mark it as "answered"

Comment: sure, please do, I believe someone else will find it useful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the data as a "normal" post instead of a json string.

To convert an array into post data to be used with `curl` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, you can use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) method.

Example:

```
$post_info = http_build_query(array(
    "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
    "method"  => "get",
    "id"      => 1,
    "params"  => array(
          "2145359"
    )
));
```